# swipe tableViewCell to delete an item

Tags: swift, xcode

I want to delete a Unit from my Core Data Application. When user presses delete button on the Cell, I present a warning.

the code was

```
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning!", message: "Are you sure to delete \"\(currentUnit)\" and all of its containing objects?", preferredStyle: .Alert)
```

I wanted to update the warning message with the objects count so I wrote

```
 currentUnitObjectsCount = getSelectedUnitObjectsCount() //Which connects to database and returns just an integer

let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Delete",handler: { (action, indexPath) -> Void in

        let currentUnit = self.units[indexPath.row].title!

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning!", message: "Are you sure to delete \"\(currentUnit)\" and all of its \(currentUnitObjectsCount) containing objects?", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let yesAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default) /* handler: { (action : UIAlertAction) -> Void in */ { (action : UIAlertAction) in                
            if let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext{

                let unitToDelete = self.fetchResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Unit

                managedObjectContext.deleteObject(unitToDelete)



                do{
                    try managedObjectContext.save()
                }catch{
                    print(error)
                }
            }

        self.checkUnits()

        }

        let noAction = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
            (action : UIAlertAction!) -> Void in

            tableView.reloadData() //to return the tableView to its normal view

        })

        alert.addAction(yesAction)

        alert.addAction(noAction)

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

               })
        deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        return [editAction]
    }
```

Now when i swipe the tableViewCell, it swipes but the delete button does not appear but when I tap the Delete button position in the swiped cell, the warning appears which means the button is there but I cant see it.

returning the code to the first style every thing works fine, but the second one acts very strange.

When I put this line of code

```
currentUnitObjectsCount = getSelectedUnitObjectsCount() //Which connects to database and returns just an integer
```

just after the the

```
    let deleteAction = ...

currentUnitObjectsCount = getSelectedUnitObjectsCount()
 let currentUnit = self.units[indexPath.row].title!
.
.
.
```

and swipe a cell, rows of the table disappear

I dont find why these happen.

Comment: You should use tableView(_:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:) for swipe to delete. This will simplify your code.

Comment: I have  tableView(_:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:) in my code.

Comment: I also do have an editAction. so I used this way